# Start/Stop Continuous Azure WebJobs from Website or on call of WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs

I have a Continuous WebJob published on my Azure Portal which performs some tasks.
I want to run this WebJob on call of WebAPI & WebAPI should not wait for the response, it should run WebJob in the background. 
I have created one WebAPI & tried to call my WebJob but it is showing nothing.

**WebAPI WebJobController.cs code:**

```
public class WebJobController : ApiController
{
    public void CallWebJob()
    {
        try 
        { 
            //App Service Publish Profile Credentials 
            string username = "userName"; //userName 
            string password = "userPWD"; //userPWD 

            string URL = "https://"+username+":"+password+"@reportjobprocess.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs/ContinuousReportServiceWebJob/run";
            System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URL); 
            request.Method = "GET"; 
            request.ContentLength = 0; 
            request.GetResponseAsync(); 
            Console.WriteLine("OK");  //no response 
        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong: " + ex.Message.ToString()); 
        }
    }
}
```

I'm totally new to WebJob & WebAPI. Please help.

Comment: Instead you should create WebJob with Queue trigger(not HTTP) and put next message into corresponding queue at your controller's action.

Comment: I'm not using QueueTrigger, I'm using async Task to continuously run my WebJob Service, now I want to start and stop my WebJob through api call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WebJobs API to start/stop WebJob.

**Start**:[wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#start-a-continuous-job)

POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/start

**Stop**:[wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#stop-a-continuous-job)

POST /api/continuouswebjobs/{job name}/stop

If you want to invoke triggered webjob you could use [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job). It doesn't support stop triggered job.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

**Update** : about credentials you could refer to [this](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials).

Comment: I want to start/stop my continuous webjob on call of web api

Comment: @ Shreyas Pednekar , you could add the method  to call WebJob start/stop api,about how to call webjob API you could redfer to this site.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2016/02/01/using-the-azure-webjob-api/

Comment: I tried it, it is showing "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'." whenever I call the web api

Comment: @Shreyas Pednekar, in my example and the link I pasted, it all shows it's a POST method.

Comment: @Shreyas Pednekar, any more problem? If my answer is helpful, you could mark it as the answer.